# Setting the name of a javascript variable using Django variable

Tags: javascript, django

Curious one - how do you set a javascript variable’s name to that of a Django variable?

I need something like:

```
var “{{django_variable}}” =
```

I’ve tried this but the script just sees `var “” =`

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you verified that you are providing a property named "django_variable" in context when you render this template?

Comment: @Alan Yes, the variable I’ve referenced if used anywhere else renders correctly.

Comment: I don't think you can do that per se, but you can do what you want to do by creating an object and dynamically setting a property name instead of a standalone variable

Comment: @MichaelRoberts it works elsewhere in the same template, but not in this location? That is odd.

Comment: Incidentally, putting quotes around the variable name is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Alan I’m a stumped as you ... it’s used to set a variable that can describe the marker on a Google Map - for multiple map markers. I’m trying to generate a variable on the unique identifier that is my django_variable . I may have to create an object like the above commenter has expressed.

Comment: @Alan - it works for Django, any {{ django_variables }} need to have quotes when used inside script.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I just need a uniquely identifiable variable name - I’m generating inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine why you want to do this, but just remove the quotes.

```
var {{django_variable}} =
```

Comment: I’m creating unique variables inside a for loop - those unique variables each specify a unique event listener in the script.

Comment: (That is to say, if I generated non-unique event listeners inside the loop both event listeners would do the same thing)

Comment: An object - the js equivalent of a dict - is probably a more appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Sure, that was also raised in the comments. I think that sounds like the way forward - I could probably even look to do this server side if that’s the case. Return the dict in context?